# Gmail API PHP Client Library or api - How do send gmail draft?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-client

I got requirement to send drafted email(Gmail) on scheduled time.
I tried below code.

```
    $access_token = 'ya29.DxswidlwadllsidVeg5B67CdpLN6QR0d1nCuQmg9GaMT9iq8-zIA8O29yR9rEMM';
    //the access token is subject to change every hour
    $header = array('Content-Type: message/rfc822', "Authorization: Bearer $access_token");
    $to = '125699645855239833'; // this is a draft id.
    $line = "\r\n";
    $raw='';
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?fields=id&key=XsqwwosqldwwdssaOLwotWD6seRloXZM';
    $raw .= "id: $to ".$line.$line;
    $method_type = 1; // set as post method
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    if( $header !== 0 ){
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    }

    if( $method_type == 1 or $method_type == 0 ){
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, $method_type);
    }else{
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    }

    if( $data !== 0 ){
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $raw);
    }

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    print_r($json);
    curl_close($curl);
```

I got result after curl posting as below

Array ( [id] => r-5083530165761240787 ) but draft(Email) was not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two changes as following
Change 1: at line no.3, You need replace

```
   Content-Type: message/rfc822 to Content-Type: application/json
```

Change 2: at line no.38, You need replace

```
   $raw .= "id: $to ".$line.$line; to $raw = '{ "id": "'.$t.'" }'.$line.$line;
```

Explain: data has to be passed in raw format with content type json.

When sending a draft, you can choose to send the message as-is or as with an updated message. If you are updating the draft content with a new message, supply a Draft resource in the body of the drafts.send request; set the draft.id of the draft to be sent; and set the draft.message.raw field to the new MIME message encoded as a base64url encoded string. For more information, see drafts.send.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts